# Manga about a boy/man who is reincarnated by a goddess into a family with a powerful elf as maid

Tags: story-identification, manga, magic, isekai, reincarnation

A goddess gave four choices for a boy/man to reincarnate. He chooses a simple family but to his surprise it had a powerful elf as maid. The boy was good at magic. He also saved a princess using his necromancer golem.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Was this in full colour or mostly black & white? And do you recall the hair colour of any of the characters?

Answer (score 2):

Is this ***[Drawing: The Greatest Mangaka Becomes a Skilled "Martial Artist" in Another World](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series/u0y8moi/drawing-saikyou-mangaka-wa-oekaki-skill-de-isekai-musou-suru)***...?

From Baka-Updates:

> Akira Kamishiro was a very successful manga author, who was diagnosed with blood cancer one day. He regretted the way he lived, where he could only build up empty relationships. Angry at his mother for asking him to send her some money, he died in a car accident. He was given a chance to choose his new mother and reincarnate in another world.
>
> Akira, not wanting to have a repeat of his past life, decided to choose an ordinary but safe life.. He was reincarnated as Akira, the only son of a magic store, with his previous life's memories. He had no talent for swordsmanship or magic, but he didn’t care as he was still loved by his family. At one point, he realized that he can embody various things by "drawing a picture". That's when he noticed his cheat ability...!?
>
> This is a story of Akira who wanted to live a mediocre life in another world and his adventures to protect his peaceful place!!

A wealthy and famous manga artist dies in a car crash and finds himself in a void with video game-like menu screens in front of him.

The screens inform him that his life has ended and show him portrait images of five different women, one of whom he can select to be his mother in his next life. The screens also provide some background info about each of the women, such as the fact that one is a royal, one a millionaire, and one an immortal.

Having experienced wealth and fame already, he now desires a normal life, so he chooses a woman who's described as a commoner. He's then reborn into a family with an elf as a maid. In addition to being a maid, she's also skilled in swordsmanship and magic.

In this new world, he has magic summoning powers, and later in the story, he summons a golem to save a princess.

[image]

[image]